# Where can I get information if my computer refuses a connection?

Tags: windows-10, event-log, windows-10-v21h1

As mentioned in [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75169450), I'm having trouble connecting to "localhost": I get the error message that the connection gets refused.

As far as I know, when something happens to computer which he doesn't like, he puts a warning or error message in the event log.

Problem here is that the "regular" event logs don't say anything (Windows Logs Application, Security, Setup, System and Forwarded Events all don't say anything), and the other logs (Application and Services Logs) have a humongous number of subdirectories.

Where can I look for information on why the connection to "Localhost" might have been refused?

For your information, Docker has altered my `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file and has added following entry:

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
10.1.xxx.yyy host.docker.internal
```

... where `10.1.xxx.yyy` is the IPv4 address of my local computer.

The startup of the Docker program is described in the file `LaunchSettings.json`, which contains the following entry:

```
"DockerDevelopment": {
  ...
  "launchUrl": "http://{ServiceHost}:5128/index.html",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  ...
```

However, the entry `ServiceHost` is not to be found anywhere in the entire Visual Studio project.

In order to make `ServiceHost` to use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`, I need to know where this is declared.

Where is that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `localhost` from Docker is problematic.

Instead of `localhost`, use the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`
which will resolve to the *internal* IP address used by the host.

For more information see the post
[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. In my application, the "ServiceHost" is used and later replaced by "localhost" but I don't know where. I've edited my question accordingly. Do you know how can I make `ServiceHost` to point to `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`?